# Unable to execute Maven project with external jars as dependency

Tags: java, mysql, maven

I am using Maven repository, I am trying to connect my application with MySQL database. I have added the required `jar` file as Maven dependency in my project.

I am able to build the project successfully but when I run the project it gives `classNotFoundException`.

I have added the `jar` location in `CLASSPATH`.

[image: exception]

[image: pom.xml]

Comment: Show your pom.xml file.

Comment: please check images

Comment: You should copy and paste the error and the pom.xml into the question, because images aren't searchable. See also [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Gerold Broser is correct on top of that version it should be `5.1.37` not `5.1.37-bin`

In maven this is the dependency :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.37</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It' not only the version that's wrong. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38159289/1744774).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22mysql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mysql-connector-java%22) the `<groupId>` for `mysql-connector-java` ist just `mysql`, not *mysql-connector-java*.

As mentioned in soorapadman's answer the (older) `<version>` is `5.1.37`, not *5.1.37-bin*, the latest is `6.0.3`.

Additional hint: You don't have to declare `<packaging>jar` and `<scope>compile` explicitely, since these are the defaults anyway. (Remember Maven's core concept [*Convention over configuration*](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html).)